# jquery: set variable value upon page refresh

Tags: jquery, refresh, page-refresh

I've got a variable in my jquery that I would like to set back to zero every time the page refreshes. Right now it looks like the page is initialized with $counter == 0.  My code changes the value of $counter, but each time the page reloads it doesn't seem to be revert back to a value of zero. Is there anyway to set $counter to zero again upon refreshing of the page? (using chrome).

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    var $counter = 0

    // Do some stuff with $counter and the value of $counter changes...

});
```

Comment: doesn't make sense... javascript doesn't retain any state once page is refreshed... it runs your code all over from scratch. Need to see more code if something is not working the way you expect

Comment: `each time the page reloads it doesn't seem to be revert back to a value of zero` it does. The lifecycle of a JS variable is only as long as the page. This sounds like an XY problem. What issue are you actually trying to solve?

Comment: thanks guys, I'll check and see. Sounds like its a different problem then!